# How to uncheck parent checkbox when one of the child check box is unchecked in asp.net mvc by JavaScript or any other

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to uncheck parent check box when one of the child check box is unchecked in asp.net mvc by JavaScript or any other manually created check box in asp.net mvc.

Code

```
 <div class="admFunction">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead id="Finances">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="10">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" id="Financescheck" onchange="CheckRootValue('Finances')">
                    Finances
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    All
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <div id="erer">
                    <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanApproveCreditTransfer, new { @class = "Finances checkAll" })
                    </th>
                    <td colspan="8">
                        Approve Credit Transfers
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewTransactionCreditHistory, new { @class = "Finances checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    View Transactions/Credit History
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewTransactionCreditHistoryMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead id="Projects">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="11">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" id="Projectscheck" onchange="CheckRootValue('Projects')">
                    Projects
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewEditProjects, new { @class = "Projects checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    View/Edit Projects
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewEditProjectsMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewManageReports, new { @class = "Projects checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    View/Manage Reports
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewManageReportsMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead id="People">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="11">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" id="Peoplecheck" onchange="CheckRootValue('People')">
                    People
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanCreateNewEditProfilers, new { @class = "People checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Create New/Edit Profilers
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanCreateNewEditProfilersMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanCreateNewEditCoachesReferents, new { @class = "People checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Create New/Edit Coaches & Referents
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanCreateNewEditCoachesReferentsMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewPeopleTracker, new { @class = "People checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    View People-Tracker
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanViewPeopleTrackerMasterAccess)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead id="Advanced">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="11">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Advancedcheck" class="checkAll" onchange="CheckRootValue('Advanced')">
                    Advanced
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanDownloadFastData, new { @class = "Advanced checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Download Fast Data
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanEditItemsEmailTemplates, new { @class = "Advanced checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Edit Items and Email Templates
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanEditResources, new { @class = "Advanced checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Edit Resources
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanManageAdminFunctions, new { @class = "Advanced checkAll" })
                </th>
                <td colspan="8">
                    Manage Admin Functions
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="12">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select-all">
                    Select All
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ($('#childCb1').checked && $('#childCb1').checked && $('#childCb1').checked)
 {
    $('#parentCb').checked = true;
 }
else
{
  $('#parentCb').checked = false;
}
```

use the above code inside a function, call that function from onChange event of each child check box.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following way.

`$(".table tbody input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
      $(".table thead#Finances").find("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
       }
});`